# JSX.Element' type cannot be assigned to ReactNode' type error question

Tags: typescript, antd

I am currently working on a project using antd and typescript.​

However, during development, an error occurs saying that the type JSX.Element' cannot be assigned to the type '(item: unknown, index: number) => ReactNode'.

I specified the interface according to the type, but it's hard to find the problem, so I'm asking a question.​

Below is my current code and the error I am getting.

```
(JSX attribute) renderItem: (item: DataType) => JSX.Element
Type '(item: DataType) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type '(item: unknown, index: number) => ReactNode'.
  Types of parameters 'item' and 'item' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'DataType'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(34, 5): The expected type comes from property 'renderItem' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ListProps<unknown> & { theme?: Theme | undefined; }'
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { List } from 'antd';

import { CommentListWrapper, CommentWrapper, CommentInfo } from '@styles/postDetail/postComment';

interface DataType {
  writer: string;
  content: string;
  created_at: string;
}

const CommentList = () => {
  const data = [
    {
      writer: 'writer 1',
      content: 'Ant Design, a design language for background applications, is refined by Ant UED Team',
      created_at: '2023. 1. 1',
    },
    {
      writer: 'writer 2',
      content: 'Ant Design, a design language for background applications, is refined by Ant UED Team',
      created_at: '2023. 1. 2',
    },    
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <CommentListWrapper
        itemLayout="horizontal"
        dataSource={data}
        renderItem={(item: DataType) => ( // Error in renderItem property
          <List.Item actions={[<a key="comment-edit">Modify</a>, <a key="comment-delete">Delete</a>]}>
            <CommentWrapper
              title={item.writer}
              description={
                <CommentInfo>
                  <div>{item.content}</div>
                  <div>{item.created_at}</div>
                </CommentInfo>
              }
            />
          </List.Item>
        )}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default CommentList;
```

​

Comment: What is `CommentListWrapper`?

Comment: This is a component that styles the list component of antd as emotion.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, "what is the definition?".